# Split by "?/" does not work

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a string by: `"?/"`. My string is: `hello?/hi/hello`.

My code is:

```
String [] list=myString.split("/?/");
```

My output is: `[HELLO,hi,hellow]` but I want to see: `[hello,hi/hello]`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure why this has attracted a down-vote. You've clearly explained the problem, you've had a go, it didn't work and you showed us your desired output and actual output. To me, this is a good question (+1).

Comment: @Duncan My guess: no research effort. The OP didn't even bother to read the documentation of `String.split(String)`. So I'd rather down than up-vote this question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape `?` otherwise it is interpreted as a meta character.

The simplest pattern to meet your needs is:

```
String[] list = myString.split("\\?/");
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, you can let `Pattern.quote()` do the work for you: it accepts a string and escapes any pesky special characters that would otherwise break your literal split expression:

```
String[] list = myString.split(Pattern.quote("?/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String [] list = myString.split("\\?/");
```

Comment: Perhaps *you* should try it before posting.

Comment: Well, it's fixed now, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp should rather be `"\\?/"` (`?` needs to be escaped with a `\`)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("hello?/hi/hello".split("\\?/")))
```

Answer (score -1):

the split mechanism takes regular expressions as input so you need to escape special characters with a double backslash (which will escape to a single backslash within the string)

```
String [] list = myString.split("\\?\\/");
```

Comment: we need to escape '?' in an regular expression, not in java string, so we need to add two '\' before '?' . And '/' is not a special character, no need to escape.  The expression should be   myString.split("\\?/");